# A primitive polynomial of positive degree is irreducible over D[X] iff it is irreducible over $F[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-explanation, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

I'm trying to prove this result from Hungerford's *Algebra* (Lemma 6.13):

> Let $D$ be a unique factorization domain with quotient field $F$ and $f$ a primitive polynomial of positive degree in $D[X]$. Then $f$ is irreducible in $D[X]$ if and only if $f$ is irreducible in $F[X]$.

The proof starts with "Suppose $f$ is irreducible in $D[X]$ and $f = gh$ with $g,h \in F[X]$ and $\deg(g) \geq 1$, $\deg(h) \geq 1$". But isn't a polynomial of degree $\geq 1$ always not a unit? We have in fact this result:

> Let $D$ be an integral domain. The units in $D[X]$ are precisely the constant polynomials that are units in $D$.

Considering $g,h \in F[X]$ with $\deg(g) \geq 1$, $\deg(h) \geq 1$ doesn't imply $f$ is reducible? We have $f(X) = g(X) \cdot h(X)$ with $g,h \in F[X]$ not units. Where am I mistaken?

Comment: The "if" part is obvious by the inclusion $D[X]\subseteq F[X]$. The "only if" part is being proved by contradiction: *assume as a contradiction that* $f\in D[X]$ *is (primitive and) irreducible in* $D[X]$, *but reducible in* $F[X]$... This is exactly what your quote is stating.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I've actually forgotten the proof was by contradiction. For the "if" part I followed my lecture notes and it was proven by contrapositive. While I was reading the "only if" part I remembered that, in the "if" part, the fact that $f = g \cdot h$ with $\deg(g) \geq 1$ and $\deg(h) \geq 1$ was used to prove that $f$ is reducible in $F[X]$ and because of this I got stuck. Should I delete the question or maybe it will be useful for someone in the future?